# Blackberry Traffic Application development

Tags: blackberry, traffic

I want to create an application in blackberry that shows Traffic data or live traffic on map from a location......

i searched a lot but did not find any help regarding to this developement..... :(

can anybody help me or guide me to go forward......

Thanx in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

To begin with you need to break your question down into parts.  Then ask for help on each of those parts/tasks.  So let me take a quick stab at break this down...

- You'll need to get the current geo location.

> (java)
> http://www.riccomini.name/Topics/Mobile/BlackBerry/BlackBerryStormGPS/
>
> (WebWorks)
> http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11849/blackberry_location_568404_11.jsp

- You'll need some kinda of mapping API to get/create maps:

> (Java app)
>
> Either Google Maps :
> http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/143263-heres-how-start-google-maps-landmark.html
> OR RIM's Map API (
> http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/maps/package-summary.html
> :
> http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/Creating_a_static_image_of_a_map_1205333_11.jsp
> )
>
> (WebWorks) -- Just Google for "JavaScript and Google Map API"  -- Also, there are a couple of good books out there.

- You'll need to be able to overlay/pull the traffic information  ( If your using the Google Map API, then you could use a Google map overlay for traffic: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Traffic_Overlays )

After looking at this I would suggest you build this using the WebWorks SDK (aka blackberry widget app). I think it would be the simplest solution to integrating with Google's MAP APIs. And using WebWorks SDK would also allow your app to run on the Playbook.

Comment: sir can u provide some more help, how can i embeds java script with my blackberry application? can u provide any sample code that help me to do this plz

Comment: You should have a look at WebWorks / Blackberry Widget Applications.  http://us.blackberry.com/developers/browserdev/widgetsdk.jsp